# Is MimeKit InternetAddressList.Parse compatible with System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add?

Tags: c#, .net, mimekit

Would like to ask developers of MimeKit, how those classes correlate?

This article describes how .NET class parses.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=netcore-3.1

The only thing found for MimeKit is this:

> http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_InternetAddress.htm
>
> A mailbox address, as specified by rfc822

Who supports more cases? Would be great to see some comparison table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Net.Mail's MailAddress is actually closer to MimeKit's [MailboxAddress](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MailboxAddress.htm) class.

Likewise, System.Net.Mail's MailAddressCollection is equivalent to MimeKit's [InternetAddressList](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_InternetAddressList.htm).

Unlike System.Net.Mail, however, MimeKit also supports the `group` type of address defined by rfc822 (later updated by rfc2822 and rfc5322) which looks like this:

```
group-name: mailbox1@domain.com, mailbox2@domain.com;
```

Combined with normal `mailbox`-style addresses in a `To:` header, for example, it might look like this:

```
To: not-in-the-group@domain.com, group-name: in-the-group1@domain.com, in-the-group2@domain.com;, not-in-the-group2@domain.com
```

Back to the question in your title: Is MimeKit InternetAddressList.Parse compatible with System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add?

They are similar, but `InternetAddressList.Parse(string)` is not a drop-in replacement for `MailAddressCollection.Add(string)` because they do different things.

`MailAddressCollection.Add(string)` not only parses the string, but also appends the parsed mailbox addresses (as `MailAddress` items) to the collection.

`InternetAddressList.Parse(string)` parses the string, returning the mailbox (and/or group) address(es) as an `InternetAddressList` object.

In case that explanation wasn't clear, let's use some examples:

```
var to = new MailAddressCollection ();
to.Add ("user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com");
```

Using MimeKit, you would do the following:

```
var to = InternetAddressList.Parse ("user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com");
```

Now lets look at another example:

```
void AddDefaultRecipients (MailAddressCollection collection, string recipients)
{
    collection.Add (recipients);
}
```

To accomplish the same thing using MimeKit, you might do something like this:

```
void AddDefaultRecipients (InternetAddressList list, string recipients)
{
    var parsed = InternetAddressList.Parse (recipients);
    list.AddRange (parsed);
}
```

Does that make sense now?